# Where can I browse the sourcecode for libc online (like doxygen)

Tags: documentation, kernel, libc

Sometimes I want to look up the implementations of functions in the stdlib, I've downloaded the sourcecode, but it's quite messy.

Just greping is not really suitable because of the many hits.

Does anyone know a webpage doxygen style that has the documentation.

The same goes for the linux kernel.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm not interested in the api, I want the implementation of the api. The actual sourcecode

thanks

Comment: monkeyking, did you try my answer? Google Code search includes the complete source code.

Comment: Yes thanks, google code search seems to do what I want.

Comment: [libc source location - for download or online viewing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6481291/995714)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [this](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/Libraries_for_C_(LibC)_Documentation) for libc documentation? And perhaps [this](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/) for the kernel? There is also Google Code search; [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#BuFT5TyPBak/pub/linux/kernel/v2.4/linux-2.4.34.tar.bz2|hh9JStbEQIo/linux-2.4.34/include/acpi/acconfig.h&q=kernel&d=2) is an example search.

More on [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) You can enter search queries like this: package:linux-2.6 malloc for any references to malloc in the linux-2.6 kernel.

Edit: Google Code search is now shut down. But you can access the git repo at http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git and it has search as well.

Comment: The Novell link is broken.

Comment: This answer needs updating. Unfortunately Google Code Search is no longer, as well.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathon, I've included an alternative. Still looking for a good replacement for libc....

Comment: @jacopo answer provides a link to the git repo browser.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Malloc should not referenced in the kernel. If I know it well kmalloc or vmalloc is used instead.

Answer (score 22):

You should check if your distribution is using the vanilla GLIBC or the EGLIBC fork <s>(Debian and Ubuntu have switched to EGLIBC</s> EDIT: they switched back around 2014).

Anyway, the repository browser for GLIBC is at http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git

http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/, posted by @guruz below, is a good alternative.

The source is a bit complicated by the presence of multiple versions of the same files.

Comment: Thank you for the link to sourceware.org, formerly sources.redhat.com

Answer (score 7):

You can try http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/

It has nice navigation/hilighting similar to an IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To help navigate the source to glibc, perhaps try something like [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)?

Note: I get dumber every time I look at the glibc source, so please be careful! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU C (glibc), the functions (beyond the GNU extensions) follow [the POSIX standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/) as far as their arguments, implementation, failure and return values. If you want to peek under the hood of static members, you'll have to look at the code.

Every push (that I can remember) to try and adopt something like Doxygen for glibc was rejected for the following reasons:

1. Redundant, POSIX already documents almost everything thats exposed, as well as man and info pages.
2. Too much work initially
3. More work for maintainers

As far as the kernel goes, Linux does use a system very similar to Doxygen called [Kerneldoc](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-doc-nano-HOWTO.txt).

Answer (score 1):

You can also get *actual* Doxygen-generated docs from http://fossies.org/dox/glibc.