# libc source location - for download or online viewing?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, glibc

Sorry I know this is stupid but where is linux libc source code available?  What I downloaded from GNU didn't seem to be what I wanted, specifically I could find nothing in the pthreads function family.

Is there an online (hypertexted cross-referenced) version somewhere?

Comment: pthreads are in nptl/ folder. Right link is http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.bz2

Comment: "specifically I could find nothing" -- wow, pthreads ARE lightweight.

Comment: [Where can I browse the sourcecode for libc online (like doxygen)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1978517/995714)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most linuxes use a libc version named `glibc`.

The LXR (online cross-reference system) for glibc is e.g. <s>here http://koala.cs.pub.ro/lxr/glibc/ for 2.9 version</s> (link is broken). I must say that something may be not lxr'ed because some sources are generated in the build process, for example - as i can remember - wrappers around a system calls.

Pthreads are in `nptl/` folder. Right link to libc sources is http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.bz2 (or change 2.14 to your version)

Update: After closing of koala's lxr, there are:

1. <s>Metager with glibc: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/</s> (Served with Sun's OpenGrok, which was originally used to generate online x-ref for Solaris/OpenSolaris)
2. Google code search (I know that it was closed; but I also know it's other version which is up): <s>http://code.google.com/codesearch and try to search something glibc-specific</s>

UPD (march 2013) They killed codesearch again:

> ```
> 404. That’s an error.
> ```
>
> The requested URL /codesearch was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

UPD 2017

1. <s>Metager with glibc: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/</s>
2. There is online git by glibc authors: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git (tree is browserable at https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree)
3. Glibc git is mirrored to github (which has some searching functions) https://github.com/bminor/glibc Buildroot 2018.05 [notably uses this mirror](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2018.05/package/glibc/glibc.mk#L20).
4. There is search like google's codesearch in all debian packages: https://codesearch.debian.net/. It can search in glibc sources by "package:glibc request" request and also have file browser: http://sources.debian.net/src/glibc/

Comment: That first link seems to be broken for me.

Comment: paxdiablo, Mr.32, Thanks, just added other link to online x-ref of glibc.

Answer (score 13):

Info on the glibc repository: http://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GlibcGit

Clone it to get your own copy and search it however you like:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
```

I load it up in an IDE project (using whatever preferred IDE) and the code navigation works quite well to let me find what I'm interested in.

Browse the source online http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git

Answer (score 6):

If you're on a Debian-derived system, you can use `apt-get source libc6`. This will unpack a `eglibc-2.12.1` directory (version number might differ, of course) in your current working directory, and the pthreads support are in the `nptl/` directory below that. `linuxthreads/` is for the older threading style, in case you're an archaeologist.

Comment: To be an archaeologist he should download not a 2.12, but smth like 2.2 or 2.3 because linuxthreads are deleted (as vanilla bz2).

Comment: @osgx, I'm surprised, I figured they were going to maintain the old stuff for all eternity. Good for them. :)

Comment: I see separate linuxthreads archives at  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ Don't really know were they in the main glibc tars at any time or not. As my view, linuxthreads are better than nptl because they allows me to set separate `setitimer` in every thread. ^)

Comment: @osgx, ah, so this is a case of trusting too much in the distribution packaging.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [FreeBSD and Linux Kernel Cross-Reference](http://fxr.watson.org/).

Have fun :)

Comment: The libc sources are bit hard to find quickly. So, open http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/?v=FREEBSD-LIBC for FreeBSD libc or http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/?v=GLIBC27 for glibc-2.7