# Assembly files in glibc library

Tags: assembly, glibc

I have used `objdump -S` to get an intermix of source code and disassembled binary lines for */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6*.

Digging into the generated output shows that a considerable amount of GNU C library has been written in assembly files with .S format.

Could anyone please let me know if these .S files are for the system calls? If so, what else is covered by these assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone please let me know if these .S files are for the system calls?

The `glibc` system calls are implemented in assembly files, yes.

> If so, what else is covered by these assemblies?

*Lots* of other stuff. Off the top of my head, on `x86_64`:

- `IFUNC`s
- `PLT` stubs
- parts of the dynamic loader that actually perform `PLT` resolution,
- hand-optimized `strcpy`, `strstr`, `memcpy`, `memmove`, some trigonometry functions.

Some platforms do not have (some of the) above hand-optimized assembly routines, and have fewer `.S` files. The `PLT` resolution can not be done in pure `C`, and so is implemented in assembly on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reverse engineering them, why not simply look at the source code?  glibc is open source:  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481291/libc-source-location-for-download-or-online-viewing) refers to places on the web that the source may be browsed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since there are too many of these .S files, reading them is not that much easy. So, I would prefer to only know what functionalists in general are implemented in assembly rather than high level C.